# Export and Import of lists overrides views

Tags: 2010, backup, export

I need to move one list data from old environment to new but keep the views on the new server. I tried exporting and importing list, but it removed all the views I created on new environment. 
is there any way to back-up and restore of data with a list?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the PowerShell cmdlets *"export-spweb"* and *"import-spweb"* will bring the views along with them. For example...

```
# To export
export-spweb -identity $srcweburl -path "\\server\c$\BackupDir" -itemurl $listname -confirm -force -haltonerror -includeusersecurity -nofilecompression;

# To import
import-spweb -identity $tgtweburl -path "\\server\c$\BackupDir" -confirm -nofilecompression;
```

Comment: Sorry, I just re-read your question and realized you **do not** want to bring the old views with you. So, ignore my answer ;-/